# Use SSLv3 in the netty

Tags: java, sockets, security, netty, sslv3

I need to write a server and a client that uses the SSLv3 protocol with netty. Here is my server code:

```
private final SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(new File("/path/to/sslkeys/server.crt.pem"),
        new File("/path/to/sslkeys/server.key.pem")).protocols("SSLv3").build();

@Override
public void run() {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
                        socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(

                                sslCtx.newHandler(socketChannel.alloc()));
                    }
                })
                .childOption(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(BUFFER_SIZE))
                .childOption(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false)
                .bind(LISTEN_PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

The following is the client code that tries to connect to the server:

```
private final SslContext SSL_CTX =
            SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(new File("/home/okv/sslkeys/server.crt.pem"))
                    .protocols("SSLv3").build();
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();

    // Start the connection attempt.
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
            .channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(Channel channel) throws Exception {
                    channel.pipeline()
                            .addLast(SSL_CTX.newHandler(channel.alloc(), REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT),
                                    new Decoder(), new ServerHandler(inboundChannel), new Encoder(BUFFER_SIZE));
                }
            })
            .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
    ChannelFuture f = b.connect(REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT);
    outboundChannel = f.channel();
    f.addListener((ChannelFutureListener) future -> {
        if (future.isSuccess()) {
            // connection complete start to read first data
            inboundChannel.read();
        } else {
            // Close the connection if the connection attempt has failed.
            inboundChannel.close();
        }
    });
}
```

But unfortunately the connection is not established, the error is given:

> 11:05:55 INFO  - [id: 0xb5674d2c, L:/127.0.0.1:4444 ! R:/127.0.0.1:57180] USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)
>
> 11:05:55 INFO  - [id: 0xb5674d2c, L:/127.0.0.1:4444 !
>   R:/127.0.0.1:57180] USER_EVENT:
>   SslCloseCompletionEvent(java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)

If you remove the protocol SSLv3, then everything works. What is my error and how to use SSLv3 in netty? In advance I thank you for your answers

Comment: SSLv3 has been broken for four years and Java versions for about three years have been by default configured to not use it. Check and if necessary edit jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in your JVM's java.security file, or override that secprop in your code. And make sure you never send any information that is actually important or valuable over an SSLv3 connection.

Comment: Also just a general advice, never use SSLv3.